# What is the minimum cost of arranging the range a (n) (a [i] <= 20) such that the equal values will form a continuous segment?

Tags: algorithm, sorting, greedy

You provide 1 string: `a1, a2..an (a [i] <= 20)`

**Requirement: The minimum cost (number of steps) to swap any two elements in the sequence so that the final sequence obtained has equal values ​​that lie in succession:**

**Each step you can only choose 2 adjacent values to swap: swap (a [i], a [i + 1]) = 1steps**

example:

```
1 1 3 1 3 2 3 2

Swap (a [3], a [4])

Swap (a [6], a [7])

-> 1 1 1 3 3 3 2 2

minimum = 2
```

I need your help.

Comment: zero (if the sequence is already sorted...)? If you're looking for ideas for partially sorting, then perhaps look at timsort to get some ideas (e.g. https://dev.to/s_awdesh/timsort-fastest-sorting-algorithm-for-real-world-problems--2jhd)

Comment: Yep,  I think this is a greedy problem or found a comment that helps solve it.

Because right at its limit it has anomalous point a [i] <= 20.

And it is important that you find the optimal (minimum) value. What do you think about it?

Comment: @hellow swapping any two arbitrary elements or just adjacent swaps?

Comment: Ow thank you!
I wrote missing the bottom line of the problem!
Each step we only exchange two adjacent positions a [i] & a [i + 1]!
I'm sorry for writing missing!
But I hope you can help me

Comment: @Primusa I need your help!

Comment: @hellow see my answer - if it solves your problem please accept it by hitting the check mark next to it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that since `A[i]` <= 20 we can go ahead and enumerate every subset of all `A[i]` and fit comfortably within any time constraints.

Let `M` be the number of unique `A[i]`, then there is a `O(NM + M * 2^M)` dynamic programming solution with bitmasks.

*note that when I say moving an `A[i]` I mean moving every element with value `A[i]`*

To understand how we do this let's first consider the brute force solution. We have some set of unique `A[i]` moved to the front of the string, and then at each step we pick the next `A[i]` to move behind what we had originally. This is `O(M! * N)`.

There's one important observation to be made here: if we have some set of `A[i]` at the start of the string, and then we move the next one, the order of our original set of `A[i]` doesn't actually matter. Any move will cost the same regardless of the order.

Let `cost(subset, A[i])` be the cost of moving all `A[i]` behind that subset of `A[i]` at the front of the string. Then we can write the following:

```
dp = [float('inf')] * (1 << M) # every subset of A[i]
dp[0] = 0
for mask in range(len(dp)):
    for bit in range(M):
        # if this A[i] hasn't been moved to the front, we move it to the front
        if (mask >> bit) & 1 == 0: 
            dp[mask^(1 << bit)] = min(dp[mask^(1 << bit)], dp[mask] + cost(mask, bit))
```

If we compute `cost` naively then we have `O(M * 2^M * N)`. However we can precompute every value of `cost` with `O(1)` per value.

Here's how we can do this:

Idea: The number of swaps needed to sort an array is the *number of inversions*.

Let's define a new array `inversions[M][M]`, where `inversions[i][j]` is the number of times `j` comes after `i` in the `arr`. For clarity here's how we would compute it naively:

```
for i in range(len(arr)):
    for j in range(i + 1, len(arr)):
        if arr[i] != arr[j]: inversions[arr[i]][arr[j]] += 1
```

Assume that we have `inversions`, then we can compute `cost(subset, A[i])` like so:

```
cost = 0
for bit in range(M):
    # if bit isn't in the mask and thus needs to get swapped with A[i]
    if (subset >> bit) & 1 == 0:
        cost += inversions[bit][A[i]]
```

What's left is the following:

1. Compute `inversions` in `O(NM)`. This can be done with keeping a count of each `M` at each index in `N`.
2. Currently `cost` is `O(M)` and not `O(1)`. We can run a separate dynamic programming on `cost` to build an array `cost[(1 << M)][M]`, where `cost[i][j]` is the cost to move item `j` to subset `i`.

For sake of completeness [here](https://codeforces.com/contest/1215/submission/65212209) is a complete code written in C++. It's my submission for the same problem on codeforces. Note that in that code `cost` is named `contribution`.

Comment: Thank you!
Hope that my later questions will get help from you ... i love u 3000